# Debian Package 'ssmtp' has no installation candidate

Tags: docker, debian, ssmtp

On a debian machine, I suddenly cannot install ssmtp via the following

```
   apt-get update && apt-get install ssmtp
```

Before it was all working seamlessly up until now.

Also just an FYI.
I am doing this on a dockerFile on a debian container.

Just for your perusal this is the docker file I am running

```
FROM php:fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y \
      git g++ libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev \
      libpq-dev libxml2-dev \
      unzip zlib1g-dev \
      procps\ 
      zip \
      libzip-dev \
      ssmtp mailutils && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
      pdo_mysql mysqli curl json mbstring pdo pdo_pgsql \
      && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql

RUN echo "hostname=localhost.localdomain" > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
RUN echo "root=root@example.com" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
RUN echo "mailhub=maildev" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
RUN echo "sendmail_path=sendmail -i -t" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-sendmail.ini
RUN echo "localhost localhost.localdomain" >> /etc/hosts

ENV TZ=Asia/Manila
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

RUN curl -sSL https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -o /usr/bin/phpunit && chmod +x /usr/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, but it has to do with the fact that the package [sSMTP](https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP) package is currently unmaintained.

> This package has been orphaned since 2019-03-19. msmtp can be used as an alternative.

So the fix would be replacing your sSMTP package with the suggested [msmtp](https://wiki.debian.org/msmtp) package.